# "link is not ready" error, vanishing network interfaces

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, network-interface

I recently had a weird problem when trying to use `airmon-ng`. Here is its description:

First, I plug in my USB WLAN adapter, and type `ifconfig`. Everything goes well and I see all interfaces are configured.

Then I type `airmon-ng check kill` in order to prepare to get my interfaces in monitor mode. I sometimes have no output, I sometimes have a big output with error messages like :

```
wlan2 : link is not ready
```

then, when I type `ifconfig`, only the loopback interface appears and I can't get them back to work.
Unplugging and then plugging back my adapter does nothing, and I have no clue about what could be the cause of the problem.

The interfaces are back on reboot, so then I tried putting one in monitor mode using :

```
ifconfig wlan2 down
iwconfig wlan2 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan2 up
```

but as soon as I typed the `iwconfig` command, something (I guess it is network-manager?) puts it back in managed mode.

Then I tried turning off network-manager, and it does the same thing: my interfaces vanished again, with (sometimes) the same error messages.

What the hell is happening ?? Is there a way to prevent this ?
It worked well up to now :(

my system is Kali-linux Sana (2.0) and the USB WLAN adapter I use is TP-LInk TL-WN722N.

Comment: Are you running wpa_supplicant?  I've had a problem (Arch Linux) that looked a lot like that. `wpa_supplicant -u`, as started from `systemd`, would do almost exactly as you describe. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution other than to not run `wpa_supplicant -u`, but rather to run it for each specific interface.

Comment: didn't start `wpa_supplicant` myself. Maybe Kali does it ?